# Can’t get a “forgot account” link to display under my password input

Tags: html, css

I am practicing laying out websites and I was trying to copy the Facebook landing page. It was going okay until I tried to get the “forgot account” link to display under the password input. For some reason it drags down the e-mail input. I have no idea why. What am I doing wrong?

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.group:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

* html .group {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* IE6 */

*:first-child+html .group {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* IE7 */

.flex {
  width: 100%;
}

[class*=col-] {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  /*margin: 0px -14px -14px -14px;*/
  border: 1px orange solid;
}

.row:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0em auto;
  background-image: url(images/grid.png);
}

.col-1 {
  width: 8.3333
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.6666%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 28.5714%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.6666%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  width: 58.3333%;
}

.col-8 {
  width: 66.6666%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 83.3333%;
}

.col-11 {
  width: 91.6666%;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: green;
}


/*Header styles*/

#header-color-div {
  background-color: #3C5A98;
}

header {
  background-color: #3C5A98;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  margin: 0.5em 0em 0em 3em;
}

header form p {
  color: white;
}

header form label input {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

header form {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

form span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-color-div">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Facebook</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">

          <span>
                <p>Email or phone</p>

                <input type="email" name="email-1" placeholder="Email">

              </span>

          <span>
                  <p>Password</p>

                  <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="password">
                  <span>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log-in"></input>
                  </span>

          <div>
            <a href="#">Forgot account?</a>
          </div>
          </span>

        </form>


      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post a snapshot of the effect?

Comment: Second @outflak – it looks fine on a modern Safari browser.

Comment: How do you post a picture on here? 0.0

Comment: Using a phone to log in???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your "Forgot account?" is inside the password's `span`.

With proper indentation, this is how your HTML looks like:

```
<span>
    <p>Email or phone</p>
    <input type="email" name="email-1" placeholder="Email">
</span>
<span>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="password">
    <span>
        <input type="submit" value="Log-in"/>
    </span>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Forgot account?</a>
    </div>
</span>
```

You should probably do this:

```
<span>
    <p>Email or phone</p>
    <input type="email" name="email-1" placeholder="Email" />
</span>
<span>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Log-in"/>
</span>
<div>
    <a href="#">Forgot account?</a>
</div>
```

BTW, I'd also close the input tags.

Comment: I'm glad it did. You should click on the tick at the left of my answer to mark it as accepted, so your question doesn't stay unsolved.